# Interrupted AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask who make a call to a webservice using DefaultHttpClient().

If the execution stops for any reason (i.e. when I'm debugging and I press "Terminate"), the next call will result in a "Refused connection" or timeout.

Code called by a function within of doInBackground() :

```
    String response = null;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    SoapEnvelope env = new SoapEnvelope();
    env.setServiceNamespace(nameSpace);
    env.setMethodName(methodName);
    env.setParams(params);

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(env.serialize(), HTTP.UTF_8);
    se.setContentType("text/xml");
    httpPost.setEntity(se);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

It get stuck on

```
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Restarting app doesn't work.

If i restart the device it works again.

Why it behave like this?

Comment: Could be many reasons, but if you don't post some code or logcat output we can only guess what your problem is.

Comment: @XaverKapeller code is very simple, i added it.

Comment: Code AND logcat. Why is it refused? Do you have any internet turned on? What do you mean "If i restart the device it works again."? You mean it works initially, then it doesn't?

Comment: Please post the logcat output of the ConnectionRefused Exception